# Do you need XSRF/CSRF token for a logoff request?

Tags: security, csrf, logout, logoff

What would be the security loophole if a logoff request is not validated with XSRF/CSRF token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of Anti-CSRF tokens as a mechanism implemented on individual endpoints/requests. Ideally, such a mechanism is baked in as a critical part of the framework you're developing in.

An Anti-CSRF *may* seem redundant on a logout link, which is not what worries me here. What worries me is designing a system which allows, or rather, does not enforce Anti-CSRF mechanisms.

In this context, the CSRF may seem benign. What happens however, when the logout link is vulnerable to say, XSS? Suddenly the Anti-CSRF token is no longer there to protect you.

Always practice [Defence in Depth](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/defence-in-depth-and-how-it-applies-to-web-applications-part-1/), in that your security should be wrapped in layers, Anti-CSRF being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Could be combined with an [OWASP A10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards), e.g. the attacker also provides a return URL that points somewhere bad, e.g. a fake "sign on again" page where he can capture your password.

Comment: In our context, we are not taking any URL parameter as "return URL", so this should be fine for now. But I totally agree with what Juxhin wrote below, to have this idea is already dangerous. The system/code is dynamic, some day, some one may change it to the case you mentioned to support a configurable return URL, then it sucks...